# Very slow *.txt file copy in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-transfer, copy-paste

This is an issue I searched quite extensively on the web, but could not find an answer to. So probably it is not a known/common issue.
I'm on Windows 7 (I could specify more about the system, if needed). When copying txt files (doesn't matter if within C: or to other drives, and it doesn't matter if they are large or small), the speed, which usually for other file types is several MB/s, slows down to sub MB/s. What could be the reason for such an odd behavior? Thank you!

Comment: I would start by running the Microsoft tool Process Monitor (include the system process from the filter, by default it is hidden).  Also, if you perform the action from a command prompt is it quicker than Explorer.exe for example?

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus.

Comment: I tried to copy from command prompt, and I got the same speed. I tried also other copying programs, like Teracopy, and the result is the same.
One thing that I just tried was to change the extension from .txt to something else (for example, I tried .ttt) and the speed was normal! So, in some way, it has to to with the extension .txt ...

Comment: Just to be precise, the speed with the .txt extension was about 500kB/sec, while with .ttt it reached 50MB/sec

Comment: Have you tried running Process Monitor with a path filter for .txt when running the test to see what other processes might be interested in the files?  I would ensure that the system process is not filtered out.

Comment: Yes, I tried. It seems that a lot is going on, even setting the filters (a lot of RegOpenKey, RegCloseKey operations, for example). On the surface, I don't see a difference between a txt file and, for example, a mp4 file (excluding, of course, the difference in copying speed). Is there any particular entry I should look for?